# Smallest Git Folder Footprint in order to push tags

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This question is with regards to being able to create and push git tags in an Azure RELEASE pipeline.  I know how to push the tags but the Azure Release pipeline doesn't work well with using both a published artifact and repo artifact so I am thinking that in the Build Pipeline I need to zip the checked out source folder `Build.Repository.LocalPath` and push that with my other artifacts and then unzip in the release pipeline and create/push the tags there.

I don't need all the files and history/etc of the repo, I just need enough to support this process because the source code repo with all the history is 1GB zipped.

Question: How do I get my git folder to be the smallest footprint so I can unzip it later and create the necessary tags/etc. I don't need the history or even the files I just need to be able to execute these commands:

```
cd %Agent_ReleaseDirectory%\_repo
git tag  mytag
git push -f --tags
```

More Info. This is on a windows build agent.   The build pipeline pulls down the repo and commit.  I can powershell/cmd into the directory and execute any git command or delete files/etc.  I just don't know what is the most efficient way to clean up this folder (compressing and publishing the artifact is already done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute minimum clone to tag the current `master` branch in a remote repo as `v1.1` is going to be

```
git clone --template= --bare --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 -b master u://r/l repo
git -C repo tag -m 'My tag' v1.1
git -C repo push origin v1.1
```

and the clone is going to be just ridiculously tiny, like much less than 100KB.

Comment: The repo is already cloned.  Wilp that work to get it in a minimal state ?

Comment: Yes, or you could just do the initial clone `--depth=1`, the `.git` folder for that is going to be pretty damn small already, and you can put it anywhere then `git reset --hard` wherever you put it to reconstitute the work tree.

Comment: The tree=0 clone will re-fetch any content you need later from the upstream repo.

Comment: I tested this and the clone `git clone --template= --bare --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 mylocalrepo repo` creates a 256MB clone.   Any ideas?

Comment: If you're cloning locally it uses hardlinks, the storage isn't duplicated, those are just hard links to the existng files. Add `--no-local` to shut that off when you're testing. Also: the major hosting services support filtering, but not all Git servers do. . . .. hm. local clones don't support filtering at all, the `--local` and `--shared` achieve the same savings.

Comment: I will play around with it but I should mention the initial clone is done automatically, I'm not executing that command so trying to either clean up that folder after all the builds or cloning to a local folder somewhere else.

Comment: If you want to create a second, minimal clone, do it as I described, from the same source as your full automatic clone. The download to make it is much less than 100kb.

Comment: Awarded.  I ended up going a different route but this helped me learn a few things here.  Much appreciated and I hope it helps others.